# iphone sdk: drawing weird characters using custom fonts

Tags: iphone, utf-8, fonts, utf-16

I'm drawing custom fonts in a view but I'm having trouble to set correctly the map of characters. The thing is that I'm unable to draw some of the characters such as "ü", "ä", "á"... apparently because of differences between the encoding formats.

To make this simple I would want to know how I can store in a NSString a character corresponding to a position such as 0x00C9, 0x00D1 and so on. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ]  ?

Comment: ok, but how do you define the character corresponding to 0x00D1 in a UTF8 string? Also, I believe it should be UTF16

Comment: maybe this helps you:  NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: "\u00D1"];

Comment: well, that represents the wrong character (something like "Ï" instead of "Ñ"). The thing is that it seems the UTF8 encoding only allows you to use a few extra characters while UTF16 uses and extended map.I'm trying to use this font: http://www.dafont.com/sf-slapstick-comic.font